# jQuery UI dialog passing ID to popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, dialog, parameter-passing

I've been creating a Video Games Website in MCV 3 using Visual Studio and am having trouble figuring out how to pass a ID from my Page to a popup Dialog to display the correct Developer from my Database.

The Page I will put up now is my DeveloperManager Page I use to do basic CRUD and the function I'm trying to do is when I click the delete link to open a dialog asking to confirm said Developer should be deleted and then delete it.

I already have a Page call DeveloperManager/Delete that if I just click at the moment is being pass `item.DeveloperID` and that brings up the correct Developer and Deletes it when confirmed. But just out of convenience I'd like to Open that Page in a Dialog Box.

As You will see as well I've already managed to open a Dialog when I click the Create New button but that doesn't use a Parameter just opens the page creates a developer and closes it.

Here's the code for the DeveloperManager Page

```
@model IEnumerable<ReviewSite.Models.Developer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Developers</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Games","Index","GameManager")
    @Html.ActionLink("Developers","Index","DeveloperManager")
    @Html.ActionLink("Publishers","Index","PublisherManager")
    @Html.ActionLink("Genres","Index","GenreManager")
</p>

<button id="createLink">Create New</button>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Developer Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Developer URL
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) 
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class = "DeveloperName" >@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeveloperName)</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class = "DeveloperURL" >@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeveloperURL)</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.DeveloperID }, new { id = "editLink" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.DeveloperID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.DeveloperID}, new { @class = "deleteLink"})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $createDialog = $('<div></div>')
        .load('/DeveloperManager/Create')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Create Developer',
            modal: true
        });
        $('#createLink').click(function() {
            $createDialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I Click Delete it calls this Page into a Dialog

```
@model ReviewSite.Models.Developer

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Games","Index","GameManager")
@Html.ActionLink("Developers","Index","DeveloperManager")
@Html.ActionLink("Publishers","Index","PublisherManager")
@Html.ActionLink("Genres","Index","GenreManager")
</p>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete @Model.DeveloperName?</h3>
<fieldset>
<legend>Developer</legend>

<div class="display-label">Developer Name</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DeveloperName)
</div>

<div class="display-label">DeveloperURL</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DeveloperURL)
</div>

</fieldset>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/umwMU/6/

Assign the item.DeveloperID to an attribute on the link.

`@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.DeveloperID}, new { @class = "deleteLink", @devid = item.DeveloperID })`

Then use that id on the querystring when loading the html for the dialog.

```
$('.deleteLink').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var developerID = $(this).attr("devid");

    var url = '/DeveloperManager/Delete/' + developerID;
    var $deleteDialog = $('#deleteDialog').load(url, function() {
        $deleteDialog.dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            title: 'Delete Developer',
            modal: true
        });
    });
});
```